# How run subdomain in Symfony 4 with built in web server?

Tags: symfony

I read this following [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html) about subdomain.

My controller folder structure is:

- src/Controller/Admin
- src/Controller/Main

All routes are defined with annotation in controller files.

ex:

```
#src/Controller/Admin/HomeController.php
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function homepage(){...}
}

#src/Controller/Main/HomeController.php
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function homepage(){...}
}
```

So I add this following configurations in config/routes.yaml file:

```
#config/routes.yaml
main:
    host: "localhost"
    resource: ../src/Controller/Main
    type: annotation
admin:
    host: "admin.localhost"
    resource: ../src/Controller/Admin
    type: annotation
```

What I want is:

1. I run the server by using this command:

> bin/console server:start

2. the result excepted:

   - access to http://admin.localhost/ => 
     homepage method in src/Controller/Admin/HomeController
   - access to http://localhost/ => 
     homepage method in src/Controller/Main/HomeController

But only http://admin.localhost/ works and http://localhost/ get 404 with this following message: "Welcome to Symfony 4.2.2"

If I swap the order in yaml file:

```
#config/routes.yaml
admin:
    host: "admin.localhost"
    resource: ../src/Controller/Admin
    type: annotation
main:
    host: "localhost"
    resource: ../src/Controller/Main
    type: annotation
```

http://localhost/ works and http://admin.localhost/ get 404 with the welcome message

How I can run [subdomain](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html) by using [built-in web server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html).

Comment: How have you pointed `project_demo.test` to the built-in server? Did you do the same with the subdomain?

Comment: I just run bin/console server:start  and use the same for both (admin.localhost and localhost)

Answer (score 1):

I debug by using this command line

> php bin/console debug:router

Because of the same name, only the last has read:

```
@Route("/", name="home")
```

I just change the name for Admin by

```
@Route("/", name="admin-home")
```

Now it works